# Proving $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$: Can you find the flaw in the reasoning?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, fake-proofs, transpose

Proving $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$ isn't difficult. An example of such a proof can be found here: [http://www.math.ucdenver.edu/~esulliva/LinearAlgebra/ABT.pdf](http://www.math.ucdenver.edu/%7Eesulliva/LinearAlgebra/ABT.pdf)

However, if I take a slightly different approach, it doesn't work:

If  $B=(b_{ij})$, then $B^T=(b_{ji})$, and similarly, $A^T=(a_{ji})$.   Thus $B^TA^T=(b_{ji})(a_{ji}) = (\sum_k b_{jk}*a_{ki}).$ But the $(i,j) $ element of $(AB)^T$ is $(\sum_k b_{ki}*a_{jk})=(\sum_k a_{jk}*b_{ki})$, which is generally not equal to $(\sum_k b_{jk}*a_{ki})$.

What is the flaw in the reasoning? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your indices are likely the problem here, as you're overusing $i$ and $j$ and somewhat conflating them with their positions within the individual matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may also address this problem in the context of inner products, which I find simpler since it avoids the necessity of index bookkeeping, *viz*:

For any matrix/operator $C$, $C^T$ is the unique operator satisfying

$\langle x, Cy \rangle = \langle C^Tx, y \rangle; \tag 1$

then

$\langle x, ABy \rangle = \langle (AB)^T x, y \rangle; \tag 2$

but

$\langle x, ABy \rangle = \langle A^Tx, By \rangle = \langle B^TA^Tx, y \rangle; \tag 3$

combining (2) and (3) yields

$\langle (AB)^T x, y \rangle = \langle x, ABy \rangle = \langle B^TA^Tx, y \rangle, \tag 4$

which holds for all $x$, $y$; thus

$(AB)^T x = B^TA^Tx \tag 5$

binds for every $x$, whence

$(AB)^T  = B^TA^T. \tag 6$

$OE\Delta$.

Comment: I have this proof posted elsewhere somewhere on the site. But it's not addressing the OP's misunderstanding of his own notation :P

Comment: That's very elegant, nice work. I haven't seen this approach before; do you have a reference for the operator/inner product relationship you mentioned at the beginning? And in line (6), should there still be an x on the left side, or does that cancel with the one on the right? Thank you.

Comment: @HankIgoe:  you're right, the "$x$" must go, will edit. Equation (1) is a more-or-less standard definition of $C^T$ over inner product spaces in many texts on the subject; try a little googling.

Comment: @HankIgoe:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose.  Also various books.  As I recall Serge Lang uses this definition.

Answer (score 5):

When you write $A^\top = (a_{ji})$, you have to remember that you're writing down the $ij$-entry. So, yes, the $ij$-entry of $B^\top A^\top$ is $\sum (B^\top)_{ik}(A^\top)_{kj} = \sum b_{ki}a_{jk}$. You just wrote symbols and didn't think about actual entries of actual matrices.

Comment: But then why is $B^TA^T=(b_{ji})(a_{ji}) = (\sum_k b_{jk}*a_{ki})$? Or is that true, and if not, why not?

Comment: No, it's not correct. Your symbolic manipulation has no meaning. You’re writing symbols without regard for meaning.  How is $b_{jk}$ the $ik$-entry of $B^\top$? Hint: It's not.

Comment: It's not saying that. It's saying that the $(j,i)$ entry - with $i,j$ fixed - of the product of the tranposed matrices is the sum over $k$ (from k=1 to n, of course) of $b_{jk}*a_{ki}$. That is, the (j,i) entry is just the value obtained by taking the dot product of the jth row of B with the ith row of A, which is the definition of matrix multiplication, at least as I understand it. Canonically it would be the dot product of the ith row of the first matrix with the jth row of the second matrix, but i and j were reversed by the transpose.

Comment: No, you misunderstand your own notation. Remember my first sentence. Indeed, you need the dot product of the $i$th column of $B$ with the $j$th row of $A$.